# Node: zlib.gunzip works, but not zlib.inflate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, zip, zlib

Why is it that GZIP files I upload can be decompressed fine with `zlib.gunzip()`, but ZIP files uploaded result in an `[Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'` error from `zlib.inflate()`, using the following code?

```
if (req.body.compression == 'GZIP') {
    zlib.gunzip(body, function(err, dezipped) {
        if (typeof dezipped != 'undefined') {
            var xmlData = dezipped.toString('utf-8');
            app.parseAndOffload(req, res, xmlData);
        } else
            res.status(400).send('Could not decompress as GZIP file')
    });
    //-> Decompresses perfectly
} else 
if (req.body.compression == 'ZIP') { 
    zlib.inflate(body, function(err, dezipped) {
        if (typeof dezipped != 'undefined') {
            var xmlData = dezipped.toString('utf-8');
            app.parseAndOffload(req, res, xmlData);
        } else
            res.status(400).send('Could not decompress as ZIP file')
    });
    //-> [Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
}
```

Comment: `zlib` doesn't work with zip files.

Comment: Why dezipped is undefined sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zlib.inflate` decodes the zlib format, not the zip format.  There are [tools out there](https://github.com/mapbox/node-zipfile) for the zip format.